# Create grayscale bitmap image from byte[] in android?

Tags: android

I have to create GrayScale bitmap image from byte[]. I tried more but i am unable to

get success.  If there is any solution please add me on your success. thanks allot!!

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12154090/creating-8-bit-image-from-byte-array) answer. While not exactly the same, it should help you out. This is assuming your byte array contains rgb pixels. Realistically though you need to include more details about the bytes you are working with and the existing image structure.

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29963291/192373) seems to be the direct fit.